# NoSuchElementException using WebDriverWait

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I would really like to understand why when approaching locating an element the exact same way as previously failing.

NoSuchElementException : `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Add')]"}`

I have also tried to use something like the following but it also failed, so in order for me write a good automation code i need to get my knowledge straight with `WebDriverWait`, so i would appreciate somebody with knowledge to spend some time on this inquiry.

It does locates if i have `xpath` like this :

```
//body/div[@id='root']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]

 public void clickOnAddVehicleButton() {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(addVehicleButton));
    vehicles.addVehicleButton.click();
}
```

I am not new into Java but i am new into automation hence some areas of knowledge is missing, i ha

Base class:

```
    public class BasePage {

    protected final WebDriver driver;
    protected final WebDriverWait wait;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);
    }
}
```

The component where that button should be present :

```
public class Vehicles extends BasePage {

private static Vehicles vehicles;

private Vehicles(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

@FindBy(xpath = "//span[text(),'Add']")
public WebElement addVehicleButton;

public static Vehicles vehiclesInstance(WebDriver driver) {
    return vehicles == null ? vehicles = new Vehicles(driver) : vehicles;
}

public void clickOnAddVehicleButton() {
    vehicles.addVehicleButton.click();
}
```

Function in the service class:

```
public void addVehicle(String vehicleName, String numberPlate) {
    myAccountService.myAccountPage()
            .clickOnVehiclesTab();
    vehicles.fillInVehicleName(vehicleName)
            .fillInVehicleNumberPlate(numberPlate)
            .clickOnAddVehicleButton();
}
```

WebDriverSettings for test :

```
public class WebDriverSettings {

protected WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    loginToDevEnvironment();
}
```

And finally my test class where i am calling the service method:

```
public class VehicleServiceTest extends WebDriverSettings {

private VehiclesService vehiclesService;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    super.setUp();
    CookieService.cookieServiceInstance(driver).acceptCookies();
    HomePageService.homePageServiceInstance(driver).clickOnMyAccountTab();
    LoginService.loginServiceInstance(driver).login(loginCorrectData());
    HomePageService.homePageServiceInstance(driver).clickOnMyAccount();
    vehiclesService = VehiclesService.vehiclesServiceInstance(driver);
}

@Test
public void shouldAddVehicle(){
    vehiclesService.addVehicle("test-vehicle","test-test");
    Assert.assertEquals(1,vehiclesService.getVehicles().listOfAddedVehicles().size());
}
```

Comment: You're showing the xpath that works which does not contain any `span` element..

Comment: @AlexeyR. you are right , i have manage to click on it, however i would still like to know if i need to bring conditions like wait.until(Expected conditions or there is a default waiting time can be set ?

Comment: Yes, there is a mechanism for page objects in Selenium which is to define conditions for element readiness. You can read more about it [here](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_page_object_expected_conditions).

Comment: @AlexeyR. thank you , but if you look at my base class this is exactly what i am using there isnt it, however i am still encountering issues of element not being preset so for now have to use Thread.sleep which is not good of course

Comment: What you have is not actually the same. You can override `isElementUsable` method of your `AjaxElementLocator` (in default implementation is always returns `true`). This will narrow the condition. You can also change `10` to something more relevant to actual element loading time.

Comment: @AlexeyR. thank you very much, will try to proceed that way, would you consider this a good practice ?

Comment: Yup. By the way `Thread.sleep` is what actually under the hood of all Selenium waiting mechanisms. waiters just involve retries and set the period to sleep.

Comment: @AlexeyR. ah i see so its a wrapper, but the difference is that Thread.sleep is not dynamic which means that if you set certain amount of seconds you would have to wait for them  and webdriverwait as long as i understood continues right away once element is located, also how you are approaching object creation , i am making singleton class for every service and pom object, could you share some light on how you proceeding, or maybe you have github with some of your work? would appreciate it

Comment: Personally I do not like singletons. However sometimes it is necessary to have ones. Especially if you integrate your tests with some frameworks like Cucumber. On github I only have a [small lib](https://github.com/webelement-click/parameterized-findby) helping to make `@FindBy` annotations more flexible.

Comment: @AlexeyR. thank you for your time once again, but why avoid singleton ? you would create objects in the heap memory again and again so it will end up having duplicates? could you explain your way of thinking?

Comment: I rely on garbage collector. When you develop a framework that probably makes sense to have consistent architecture. But page objects are "client-side" objects, they are usually not on framework side. You create them in your tests so that you can put less effort to thinking of architecture and more effort to scripting your test logic.

Comment: @AlexeyR. thanks for your comments Alexey i hear your point, i will take your advice on AjaxElementLocator, however regarding relying on a garbage collector i guess its a preference approach, i also dont like the fact that people combine webelements and all the service methods in POM class,  which is why i have a service separately created , but again maybe your approach is a better way to go forward , i will read more regarding it if i can find something online, thank you for your time you and prompt respondings

Comment: @AlexeyR. i wanted to take this to chat to ask some questions but i do not have enough reputation, is there a way to open a chat from your side, i have some questions and you seems to know a lot :)

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/223769/nosuchelementexception-using-webdriverwait?tab=general

Comment: @AlexeyR. not enough reputation :D  maybe i can contact you , again its your personal time so if you do not want to waste it dont worry i completely understand. I just cant get my head around

Comment: @AlexeyR. could you please look into it again if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711031/invalid-session-id-when-running-multiple-tests