# Invalid session id when running multiple tests

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I have raised that question previously, but nobody seemed to be able to answer it. Therefore I will go ahead and post a question one more time with the current code structure:

I have a parent with a `@BeforeEach` method that sets up everything:

```
public class WebDriverSettings {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        loginToEnvironment();
    }


    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
    }



private void loginToEnvironment() {
        String TARGET_URL = System.getProperty("TARGET_URL", "");
        String URL = " + "@" + TARGET_URL;
        driver.get(URL);
    }
```

Than it's a parent's child, one of the tests classes:

```
public class LoginServiceTest extends WebDriverSettings {

    private LoginModal loginModal;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        loginModal = HomePage.homepageInstance(driver)
                .acceptCookies()
                .closeCovidMessage()
                .clickOnMyAccountTab()
                .switchToLoginTab();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessfullyLogin() {
        assertEquals(userName, loginModal.login(loginCorrectData()).myAccountName.getText());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDisplayIncorrectCredentialsMessage() {
        loginModal.login(loginIncorrectData());
        assertEquals(incorrectCredentialsMessage,loginModal.wrongCredentials.getText());
    }
```

Example of pom object, in which way all my pom objects are build :

```
ublic class LoginModal extends BasePage {

private static LoginModal loginModal;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='email']")
public WebElement emailInputField;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='password']")
public WebElement passwordInputField;

@FindBy(css = ".button-hover-wrapper > div.button-inner")
public WebElement loginButton;

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Log In']")
public WebElement loginTab;

@FindBy(css = ".error-info")
public WebElement wrongCredentials;

private LoginModal(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public static LoginModal loginModalInstance(WebDriver driver) {
    return loginModal == null ? loginModal = new LoginModal(driver) : loginModal;
}

public HomePage login(Login login) {
    loginModal.clickOnLoginTab()
            .fillInEmail(login.getEmail())
            .fillInPassword(login.getPassword())
            .clickOnLoginButton();
    return HomePage.homepageInstance(driver);
}

public LoginModal clickOnLoginTab() {
    loginModal.loginTab.click();
    return loginModal;
}

public LoginModal fillInEmail(String email) {
    loginModal.emailInputField.clear();
    loginModal.emailInputField.sendKeys(email);
    return loginModal;
}

public LoginModal fillInPassword(String password) {
    loginModal.passwordInputField.clear();
    loginModal.passwordInputField.sendKeys(password);
    return loginModal;
}

public void clickOnLoginButton() {
    loginModal.loginButton.click();
}
```

}

From my understanding, my code does the following:

`setUp` method in parent runs each time before the test, than `setUp` method in the child starts to run, which successfully opens a browser and completes the test. However, when it goes to another test, I get the following:

```
    invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Artjoms-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10eb:9260:8538:39df%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.6', java.version: '15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 86.0.4240.183, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 86.0.4240.22 (398b0743353ff..., userDataDir: /var/folders/z6/46cwjtvx2fj...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56802}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 9837fd96a4efca85f4bcdbf90fea8a77
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.cookie-accept-all}
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
```

Current dependencies stack:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.5'
    compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '4.2.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}
```

Comment: Are you running them sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: overall looks working in my pc..Share your other code
like login, loginToEnvironment

Comment: @ZakariaShahed added the code requested, thank you

Comment: @AlexeyR. I assume in a logical order so sequentially

Comment: I would start with removing `static` modifier from `WebDriver` field. I cannot see the reason it has to be static.

Comment: @AlexeyR.  its just a mistake to be honest i had it not static and nothing changed, i will upload a little piece to my github and send it to you, i am so tired of not understanding it :(

Comment: @AlexeyR. could you start the chat ? i have enough points not to open it.

Comment: Sure. Also can you provide the full exception stack trace so that we know where exactly the failure happens.

Comment: @Prozorov https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224192/room-for-alexey-r-and-prozorov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that the page objects are designed in Singleton way:

```java
public static LoginModal loginModalInstance(WebDriver driver) {
    return loginModal == null ? loginModal = new LoginModal(driver) : loginModal;
}
```

So that once initialized with a driver in first test they remain refering to old driver instance (which has been already closed) in new test.

The solution would be to rework `loginModalInstance` and other similar methods so that they re-initialize the fields of existing objects with new driver instance.